# Armature not animating in Blender Game mode?

Tags: animation, game-engine, armature, export

I'm relatively new to blender and I'm currently trying to put an animation of Shrek performing the Gangnam style dance into Augmented Reality however I seem to have ran into some bumps in the road.

The blend file is very simple, a looping animation using the always game logic sensor and the animations play great in timeline view, but when I try and press P in Blender Game Shrek disappears which I find odd.

I've tried deleting the armature modifiers in the modifiers menu on the character model but when this happens there is no deformation of the character model in timeline view, and when importing the file into Unity there is no animation here either, apart from in the animation preview which I'd guess say would be the equivalent of Blender's timeline view.

Would anyone be able to offer any advice? I'm sure it's pretty simple.

Cheers,

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found out that it was because I was applying the game logic to the objects for the character model instead of the armature. May be worth knowing for anyone else that may have the same problem though!